# Ubuntu dhcpd server, different subnets to clients

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to get a ISC DHCP server running on an Ubuntu 14.04.2 server. Whenever I try to start the DHCP service it stops instantly and this is logged and the service stops:

```
2015-05-15T21:23:16.600736+00:00 ubuntu dhcpd: No subnet declaration for eth0 (10.126.88.2).
2015-05-15T21:23:16.600743+00:00 ubuntu dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
2015-05-15T21:23:16.600749+00:00 ubuntu dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
2015-05-15T21:23:16.600755+00:00 ubuntu dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
2015-05-15T21:23:16.600762+00:00 ubuntu dhcpd:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
```

My dhcpd.conf file looks like this:

```
option ztp-file-server code 150 = { ip-address };
option space ZTP;
option ZTP.image-file-name code 0 = text;
option ZTP.config-file-name code 1 = text;
option ZTP.image-file-type code 2 = text;
option ZTP.transfer-mode  code 3 = text;
option ZTP-encap code 43 = encapsulate ZTP;
subnet 10.194.74.0 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
authoritative;
   option routers                  10.194.74.1;
option subnet-mask              255.255.255.128;
default-lease-time              28800;
max-lease-time                  32200;
range                           10.194.74.10 10.194.74.11;
option ztp-file-server 10.1.1.2;
option ZTP.image-file-name "/jinstall-qfx-5-13.2X51-D35.3-domestic-signed.tgz";
option ZTP.transfer-mode "http";
option ZTP.config-file-name "/template.conf";
}
```

I'm trying to do some juniper zero touch provisioning stuff, so thats what all the ZTP stuff is referring too.

I've put eth0 into the etc/default/isc-dhcp-server 'interfaces' section.

Any ideas whats going on here?
The DHCP clients are on a remote network, does it matter that the DHCP pool is on a different subnet to eth0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dhcpd` needs a subnet declaration for its `eth0` physical NIC.

You need to add it in your `dhcpd.conf`, but just leave it blank if you don't want to use it :

```
subnet 10.126.88.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
}
```

I let you adjust the subnet mask according to your network